# create a new column conditioned by blank cells in two different columns

Tags: powerbi, dax, powerbi-desktop

I would like to create a new column so that I would obtain 0, if in one of the two of them there is blank, then the value is 0, otherwise is 1

[image]

Somehow it seems that IF function does not work with me and maybe so it is for ISBLANK() but I could try to do an attempt. Could you please help me?

Thanks

Please just consider the null item as blank cells

Answer (score 1):

You should in future share what code you have tried.

```
My New Column =
  IF( ISBLANK([A]) || ISBLANK([B]), 0, 1)
```

And if that doesn't provide the expected results, then maybe column A has empty string and not null. So then try:

```
My New Column =
  IF( ISBLANK([A]) || [A] = "" || ISBLANK([B]), 0, 1)
```

Comment: Both of them gives an error message as expeceted token ','.

Comment: Share a snip of the error, I suspect you are wanting PowerQuery instead of DAX